# php string comparison fails with self::mystring

Tags: php, digest-authentication

The below class shows my situation - I am not getting the right results.

```
class Test {
    public static $API_KEY = 'B0gTFoDazzV7e1EgutQg';
    public static $API_SECRET = 'S5axjxfvpO2uNPocdXE';

    public function test(){

        $a=  self::$API_KEY.":".self::$API_SECRET;
        $'B0gTFoDazzV7e1EgutQg:S5ddjxfvpO2uNPocdXE';
           if ($a==$b){
                 echo "True";
                 echo var_dump($a);
                 echo var_dump($b);
           } else {
                 echo "False";
                 echo strlen($a);
                 echo strlen($b);
                 echo var_dump($a);
                 echo var_dump($b);
          }

    }
}


$a=  new Test;
```

This should be the same! It should be true...

This should be TRUE!! any ideas/?>

Comment: This has no reason to fail. Is this your complete code? Nothing between `curl_setopt` and `$a=...; $b=...;` ?

Comment: Can you check the value of `var_dump($a.':'.$b == 'B0gTFoDazzV7e1EgutQg:S5ddjxfvpO2uNPocdXEev.J5Gjargwmcc0JA5jeIGyzXhZuHphwfe')`? It could be some issue with your strings...

Comment: So your variable is incorrect. Did you trying to echo `self::$API_KEY.":".self::$API_SECRET`? Does it look the same?

Comment: Try taking the static string, and copy paste it again in your fields. There's clearly something wrong with your strings if they 'look' identical but `==` returns wrong.

Comment: omg = ive been copying pasting and trying for over an hour. Ive been copying the wrong details over consitently. Admit that its a typo. im gonna crawl into a hole and beat my self..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two strings are not the same...

```
 api_secret:  S5axjxfvpO2uNPocdXEev (first part)
                ^^
 compared to: S5ddjxfvpO2uNPocdXEev
                ^^
```

Comment: Just goes to show you: when a language supposedly "fails" at simple string comparison... Well, then its usually not the language failing. :P